# Vue3 make hover state / button remain after unhovering

Tags: css, button, vuejs3, hover

I'm trying to include a tansition in a :deep(.splitpanes__splitter:hover) element so that the button that appears when hovering over the splitter remains after unhovering. Because otherwise I am not able to click on this button, as it is gone before I could click on it.
Unfortunately, I have not yet managed to find out where I have to install the transition and how, so that it works. So I would really appreciate your help.

The following HTML code, is what I have given (simplified):

```
<splitpanes class="splitpane">

      <pane>
      </pane>

      <pane>
        <v-tooltip>
          <template>
            <v-btn class="scaling-button">
              <v-icon></v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <span></span>
        </v-tooltip>
     </pane>

</splitpanes>
```

The splitter, which is responsible for resizing the splitpanes, is only a pseudo element and is addressed in css as follows:

```
:deep(.splitpanes__splitter){}
```

This is the css code I already have. The hover effect itself works perfectly. Only the transition unfortunately does not:

```
<style>
.scaling-button {
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  height: 30px !important;
  max-width: 15px;
  min-width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid #00000056;
  box-shadow: none;
}
</style>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.splitpanes__pane {
  border-radius: 8px;
}

:deep(.splitpanes__splitter:hover) {
  background-color: red;

  + .splitpanes__pane .scaling-button {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0s ease 1s; /*delay 1s*/
  }
}

:deep(.splitpanes__splitter) {
  top: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 8px !important;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #00000056;
}

:deep(.splitpanes--horizontal .splitpanes__splitter) {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 30px !important;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

:deep(.splitpanes--horizontal .splitpanes__splitter:nth-child(2)) {
  display: none;
}

</style>
```

With the variant given above, the button unfortunately disappears just as quickly as without transition.
Then I have already tried to insert the transition at the following position. It worked for the red color on the splitter, but unfortunately not for the button:

```
:deep(.splitpanes__splitter:hover) {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0s ease 1s; /*delay 1s*/
  + .splitpanes__pane .scaling-button {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I have also tried the two solutions to the StackOverflow questions already given. transition:0s 180s; and transition 0; unfortunately don't work for the button either.

If you have any idea what I am doing wrong, I look forward to your solution.
Thank you very much.